# Не открывается 443 порт на CentOS 7. Открывал порт в iptables и дизейблил firewalld

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, port

Не открывается 443 порт на CentOS 7. Открывал порт в iptables и дизейблил firewalld. 
Открытые порты в iptables:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4021 packets, 4648K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    5   272 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW
    3   172 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW

```
Nmap scan report for server1.migrationto.us (162.213.253.196)
```

Host is up (0.00046s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
111/tcp open  rpcbind

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, что я сделал. Я менял /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

Nmap scan report for server1.migrationto.us (162.213.253.196)
Host is up (0.0000080s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
111/tcp open  rpcbind
443/tcp open  https